# Concat ARM Template DiskName

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to concatenate a disk name, but I'm having trouble. I can concat with the following, which has parameter first, with no issues

```
"Newvm02OSDiskName": "[concat(Parameters('Newvm02VMName'), '-osdisk')]"
```

But when I try to add `"dsk-"` at the front I get an error.

```
"Newvm02OSDiskName": "[concat('dsk-', (Parameters('Newvm02VMName'), '-osdisk'))]"
```

Can't see where I'm going wrong, help please :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parenthesise the last 2 arguments:

```
"Newvm02OSDiskName": "[concat('dsk-', Parameters('Newvm02VMName'), '-osdisk')]"
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry that was a bit premature from me, still getting an error. `"[concat('dsk-', Parameters('VMName'), '-osdisk')]",` doesn't work, is that right or have i made an error?

Comment: error `      {
        "code": "DiskProcessingError",
        "message": "One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk instance view for details."
      }`

Comment: well, can you show the error its talking about? this `concat` is definitely valid.

Comment: `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 01:04:41 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'vm-new01' failed with message '{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
"code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
"message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
"details": [
{
"code": "DiskProcessingError",
"message": "One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk instance view for details."`

Comment: @4c74356b41 Hope that's readable, but the error suggests it's the disks `"code": "DiskProcessingError",
"message": "One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk instance view for details."` I think

Comment: Don't put all this in comments. Add the error message and your template to the question.

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks for your help. The code you gave me worked, the error was related to the fact the disks already existed and I was using the create option not the attach option. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again for your help.